# Use alfresco ged with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cmis

I have a problem using the alfresco api with laravel,
I try to install php-cmis client with composer via composer (composer require dkd/php-cmis), and it gives me this error , Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- dkd/php-cmis[dev-master, 2.x-dev] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.8).
- dkd/php-cmis[v0.1, v1.0.0, ..., 1.0.x-dev] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, ..., 5.3.x-dev] but there is a conflict with the root composer.json require file (^7.8).
- dkd/php-cmis 2.x-dev is an alias of dkd/php-cmis dev-master and therefore requires its installation.
- Root composer.json requires dkd/php-cmis * -> satisfiable by dkd/php-cmis[dev-master, v0.1, v1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.x-dev, 2.x-dev (dev-master alias)].

Use the --with-all-dependencies (-W) option to allow upgrades, downgrades and deletions of packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running compose require with an explicit version constraint, for example "compose require dkd/php-cmis:*" to find out if a version is installable, or "compose require dkd/php-cmis:^2.1" if you know which one you need.
The installation failed, returning ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original contents.

It tells me that ghuzzle http required is version 6, just that when I try to install version 6, laravel won't accept a version lower than version 7 because I'm using laravel 10

there is an image of error
[image]

Comment: `dkd/php-cmis` has seen the last activity nearly four years ago, I highly doubt that you want to use that package. But yeah, it requires Guzzle v6 and that is also pretty outdated

Comment: Thank you for your response, what alternative are you suggesting to me